# Email address not show in Django registration form

Tags: django, forms, email, registration

I have a very basic registration form, asking the user for his username and password (twice).
Now I want to add a field for the email address, as I want to add 'reset password' functionality.

I found the following code to do add the email field:
https://gist.github.com/schwuk/2725286
and I am using this extended form.

However, the email field does not show up in my registration form. 
The template for this form looks like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Create an account{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Create an account</h1>
<form action="/app/register/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type="submit" value="Create the account">
 </form>
{% endblock %}
```

This is the relevant part of views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404 
from .forms import DocumentForm, MyUserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import auth

def auth_view(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')
    user = auth.authenticate(username = username, password = password)      

    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/app/home/')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/invalid')


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            return HttpResponse("Registration was succesful")
    else:
        form = MyUserCreationForm()
        return render(request, "registration/register.html", {
                    'form': form,})
```

Comment: Please show your view and form. It's better to include the code in your question, instead of linking to an external site.

Comment: The form looks good. You'll need to post your views.py. It must be the culprit.

Comment: add your `MyUserCreationForm` class please